# Disable closing Google's Chrome browser after closing last tab

Tags: google-chrome

I'm used to this way from firefox, and it is incredebly annoying. Is there a way to disable that behaviour in Chrome as well (when one tab is open, and you click C-w, it will close the browser as well) ?

Comment: It sort of bugged me the first time, until I started it up again, and it took all of 1 second to start. The browser starts to fast anyway it doesn't matter.

Comment: I know. But I'm a man of habits in regard to browser behaviour, so it annoys me to no end.

Comment: Isn't that now the same behaviour in Firefox?

Comment: @e_ho - Yes, but in firefox it can be changed.

Comment: @e_no - and in some older versions it used to be the default, so ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this a lot as well, but I fear that it's working "as intended".

From [Google Chrome Help:](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95631)

> Closing the last tab in a window also
>   automatically closes the window.

The comment in the question made me try something:

if you have multiple windows of Chrome open and you accidently kill one of them with your Ctrl+W-ing, you can restore the window by hitting Ctrl+Shift+T.

I haven't been able to test if this also works if you close all windows and have to launch Chrome again

Answer (score 9):

There is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dlopnnfglheodcopccdllffcijjeenkj) that can help with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution that I stumbled on was to "pin" one of my tabs (usually Gmail, but why not SuperUser?) which leaves it permanently as the leftmost tab, and without a close tab button. It's essentially the manual version of @wasia 's suggestion.

Comment: Except in cases where the user uses CTRL-w to close tabs, it's closed all the same.

Comment: +1 : I don't usually use ctrl+w so this was a decent answer without having to install an extra extension. Thanks!

Comment: I typically use C-w and this is helpful to me :)